# low rendering with the big data in teechart pro vcl

Tags: delphi, rendering, teechart

i use teechart pro vcl for plot charts from input data.
i read data from comport and add points to TFastlineseries with this code :

```
var
  a : integer;
  b : double;
-----------------------------
With Dbchart1.Series[0] Do
Begin
   Series0.AddXY(a, b, '', clTeeColor);
end;
```

i have very simple 2d or sometimes 3d colorfully graphs with more than 100000 points. but after 20000 points the rendering gets very slow and in some place it will be stop.
what can i do!? is there any algorithm for improve this situation?

Comment: You could ask yourself what is the resolution of your screen or printout. Then ask yourself why you want to plot 100.000 or even 'only' 20.000 points.

Comment: Perhaps you could group the values in groups of 200 or 500 and calculate a mean value for each such a group and plot those.

Comment: actually at the first ( in hardware ) the  mean value calculated and these data are result of that. all of these points are important and we can`t reduce it. we need all points for save in database but in real-time show maybe need to 300 points at the same time . i want somethings like the ECG for show the time-varying graph.

Comment: **You should edit your question** (use the 'edit' button under the tags of your q) and add that information. Adding data to the db is of course one task and displaying another. So, if I understand, you want to have a graph of about 300 points and it should be constantly scrolling (or do you mean sweeping). I don't know how to do that with `TeeChart`, but maybe somebody else can chime in. But it is important that you edit your question!

Comment: Also indicate at what pace (speed) new values come in.

Comment: My problem is the low render and the graphics issue. The data is stored in db without any problems. I've just explained to make it clarify

Comment: sample rate = 1000 ~ 3000 sample per second

Comment: I repeat: **You should edit your question!** Details in comments are often overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off drawing all the points.

```
  Series0.DrawAllPoints := false;
```

From [Real-time charting in TeeChart VCL](https://www.steema.com/docs/TeeChartVCLRealtime.htm):

TFastLineSeries introduces several properties for fast drawing

- The DrawAllPoints boolean property, default value True. Normally
  chart size is limited to a fixed number of screen pixels. This means
  that if, for example, you have 1.000.000 points, they will inevitably
  "share" the same screen pixel coordinate (in horizontal, vertical or
  both directions). Drawing an algorithm will then plot multiple points
  with different real x,y coordinates at the same screen coordinate.
  After multiple calls to drawing the algorithm and waste of cpu time
  you'll end up with a single painted screen pixel. In this case a
  reasonable thing to do is group the points with the same x screen
  pixel coordinate and replace them with two points (group minimum and
  maximum values). The end result will visually be the same as drawing
  all the points in the group. But it will be a lot faster, especially
  if there are lots of points per group. Setting DrawAllPoints to False
  does precisely that : the internal algorithm processes data and draws
  only non-repeated (group) points. Using this trick you can plot
  millions of points in realtime with little fuss.

The PDF also mentions how to delete from a series in real time.

- Series Delete method. The Delete method now includes a second
  parameter which controls how many points will be deleted from a
  series. This allows fast delete of multiple points in a single call,
  which is much faster than deleting multiple points using a loop.